# SubSonic.SqlQuery Distinct

Tags: subsonic

How do you do DISTINCT with SubSonic.SqlQuery and not Query? I am using Subsonic 2.1 and can't seem to find DISTINCT

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it for ActiveRecord, but I don't think it's that much different from RepositoryRecord:

```
DB.Select().Distinct().From<Product>().....
```

Answer (score 0):

DB.Select().From().Distinct().....